# What is Altbier?

Tags: german-beers

Altbier is found in Dusseldorf.

**Is Altbier "alt" (i.e. "old" in german) because they are aged like wine?**

**Can altbier be found outside of Dusseldorf?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Beer Advocate](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/style/86/]/), a longer than normal conditioning period is one possible reason for it being an "altbier". A second explanation is that it's tied to Latin and refers to the rising yeast.

Quite a few breweries outside Dusseldorf make altbiers (or have made, at least). That BeerAdvocate page lists

Answer (score 2):

Essentially it is an ale that ends up being lagered after the primary fermentation is completed.

The malts used are primarily pilsen, which is normally used in lagers.
Not a lot of hop flavor and aroma, some bitterness but a closer malt/hop balance.

> Altbiers are light copper to light brown ales with white heads. The beer is very clear due to the lagering. The aroma is slightly malty, with almost no hop aroma. The flavor is bitter. Not an IPA bitter, but still a firm bitter flavor. Some of the altbiers have a light caramel flavor, which I like, and is followed by a dry finish. The beer could be compared to a hoppy Vienna style lager. The alcohol content of the beer is lower than average, usually between 4.5% to 5.2%. This makes altbiers a great session beer.
>   quoted from link below.

[German AltBier - Homebrew](http://www.fermentarium.com/homebrewing/brewing-beer/great-altbier-german-ale/)